# Inverted index: Delete then Insert pattern?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have an inverted index table on a table of Users.  The table allows querying users by last name.  It is called "users_by_lastname".

Primary key of this table has "lastname" in it, so it cannot be updated.

If a user changes their last name in the main "Users" table, should I be deleting and re-inserting into the inverted index table, "users_by_last name"?

I cannot update a primary key column in Cassandra...  Are there other patterns that handle this better?

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra 3.0 you can deal with this problem by creating the inverted index table as a materialized view of the Users table. Then Cassandra will take care of maintaining the view automatically whenever you update the base table.

On earlier versions of Cassandra your only option would be to do a delete and then insert with the new last name in the application maintained inverted index table.

Comment: I tried MV and it requires all the PK fields from the main table, which will not work for my other read patterns.  I think MVs are a nice feature, but too limiting in its first release.